# Need of a copy constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

Do i need ti declare a copy constructor in this situation

Suppose we have R2 a class and u,v,w objects.

```
w = u + v;
w = r + u;
w += u;
```

Comment: Maybe. Maybe not. Hard to tell without knowing what the details of `w`, `u`, and `v` are.

Comment: Yes and no. Until you provide more details, the super-positioned answer is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code will not invoke a copy constructor, as long as =, + and += (if overloaded) take their parameters by reference instead of by value.

Comment: `operator+` should and usually does return a copy.

Comment: operator+ returns a value rather than a reference to one of the operands, yes. But that doesn't mean a copy constructor is invoked.